# Azure CDN website is slower

Tags: c#, performance, azure, cdn

I'm using Azure Website CDN. But my site without CDN is much faster  http://take.ms/tfx44 (without CDN) and http://take.ms/xliKJ (with CDN). Why CDN works slower?

Answer (score 1):

On the first request to the CDN, it was much slower, but sped up on subsequent requests. This is because the first time the file is requested in a particular POP region, it needs to get it from the origin, resulting in longer time. After that, the file is cached, and should provide better response times.

Another reason could be that you're requesting from a location close to your origin. Where is it located?
Try using a VM from another geographic location to make the request and see what the result is then.